# How to show the android preferences activity inside a popup window?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow, preferencescreen

I have a functioning settings activity (the default one that Android studio generates) which I would like to display inside a `PopupWindow`.

I researched how to do this and most answers that show how to display an activity inside a popup window involve directly inflating the activity layout during the creation of the popup window.

I have a `SharedPreferenceChangeListener` that works in conjunction with the existing settings activity to monitor preference changes in realtime. My question is, would inflating the layout with the `PreferenceScreen` directly preserve the listener's behavior for the preference items?

I could write a separate layout for the `PopupWindow` and attach listeners during creation for the controls inside the popup window layout, but it would be nice to use the easy layout creation and coupling with `SharedPreferenceChangeListener` that Android already provides.

Looking forward to your responses. Thanks in advance!